# Will JavaScript random function ever return a 0 or 1?

Tags: javascript

Can JavaScript's `Math.random()` ever return exactly a 0 or 1?

Comment: According to the documentation, Math.random() will return a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). The important part is inclusive/exclusive. Inclusive means it's included, exclusive means it's not. So Math.random can return a 0 (because it's inclusive) but not a 1 (because it's exclusive)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the ECMAScript specification:

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0
>   but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately
>   uniform distribution over that range, using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no
>   arguments.

Source: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.14

Comment: so. am I right to assume that randomly selecting an array element using random, would never select the final array value i.e Math.floor(Math.random() * namesArray.length) ??

Comment: @Hightower If there are 3 array elements, then `Math.random() * namesArray.length` will be a number in the range `[0, 3)`, which can be divided equally into `[0, 1)`, `[1, 2)`, and `[2, 3)`. If the number is in the last section, e.g., `2.4`, then `Math.floor` with result in `2` which is the index of the last array element.

Answer (score 7):

Yes and No, in that order.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range `[0, 1)` that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

Answer (score 4):

Yes to 0, no to 1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

> Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1)
>   that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive),
>   which you can then scale to your desired range.

Answer (score 3):

It will not return 1

> Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random